# Going back to list in Drill-Down Navigation Based Application using Core Data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uinavigationbar

I want to build a simple drill down app (similar to the Contacts app on the iPhone). I am using Xcode 4.0.

I start by making a new "Navigation Based Application", and also say that I will be using Core Data for storage. I then go and add 'New File' and select UIViewController, and a subclass of UIViewController.

In my RootViewControler (which was made in the template) at didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I do the following:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

TrackerDetailViewController *trackerView = [[TrackerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrackerDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

trackerView.title = [managedObject valueForKey:@"trackerName"];

trackerView.referringObject  = managedObject;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:trackerView animated:YES];

[trackerView release];
```

And this works - I can load up some details in TrackerDetailViewController.

What I cant seem to figure out is how to go back! Most places I am reading online say that this should be happening automatically. I can't seem to get that to happen. If I download a few samples and compile them, they do have a back button - but I dont see how it was added or managed, and can't find what I am missing to not have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `[managedObject valueForKey:@"trackerName"]` is actually returning anything.  If not, then there's no title, and no back button will be created.

Oops, just re-read your code.  It's the parent that needs a title assigned.  Add something like `self.title = @"myName;` and myName should then appear as your back button in trackerView.

Comment: Yup, the second part was exactly it. I knew my managed object was getting passed ok but just had an oversight of this. I guess its pretty common sense but really easy to look over.

Comment: Well, having fallen into the same mistake, I think Apple's choice here is pretty unintuitive. It should give a "Back" button by default if the parent is untitled. (How often do you not want to go back? And if they want to allow getting rid of the back button entirely, then make that a separate ivar.  Glad I could help.